# В чём состоит преимущество использования namespace'ов и когда их нужно использовать обязательно?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Имеется ввиду создание и использование пользовательских пространств имён.

Comment: Пространства имен используются для организации кода в виде логических групп и с целью избежания конфликтов имен, которые могут возникнуть, особенно в таких случаях, когда база кода включает несколько библиотек.       Для больших проектов.

Comment: Немного отвечу на комментарий выше. `когда их использовать?` - всегда. Это правило хорошего тона, которое позволит вам отделить вашу рукопись от чужой и в 99.99% случаев предотвратит от конфликта имен. По той же причине не стоит использовать в 99.99% случаев `using namespace`, потому что этот стейтмент по сути отменяет само назначение неймспейса, делая его бессмысленным. В крайних случаях на помощь вам приходит `auto` или `using namespace_name::any_function`